# What is the most inefficient to pack convex object?

Tags: geometry

Suppose that you have an infinite number of identical $n$-dimensional convex objects.  If the objects are packed optimally (so as to minimize the interstitial space), what object would result in the most interstitial space as a proportion of all of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I can make a triangle with arbitrarily large area into which only one ball of a fixed radius will fit...  Or maybe I am reading the question backwards?  Are you trying to pack strange objects into a ball, or balls into strange objects?

Comment: That being said, I can make a rectangle of arbitrarily small area that will fit into a ball.  Only one such rectangle can fit in the ball, so I can make the "waste" as large as I like.  A similar construction generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: So squares and equilateral triangles can cover all of the plane, and circles can cover $74\%$ of it. You're asking which convex shape covers the least of the plane given optimal packing? (Similarily for higher dimensions.)

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for.  Imagine instead you have an n-dimensional hyper cube which is much much larger than your identical objects.  What object when packed optimally would leave the most unfilled space?

Comment: Yes, what @Arthur said.

Comment: @JonathanBrown a hypercuboid, with one side almost $\sqrt{n}$ times the side of your $n$-dimensional hypercube and the others almost $0$

Comment: @Henry I think you, like Xander, read too much into this "fixed ball or cube" (which is now even edited away). That's just there to help facilitate the definition and calculation of interstitial space. We are packing all of $\Bbb R^n$ with our convex objects.